# Wrapping a class instance by its own method

Tags: python

Suppose we have a python class like below:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def f(self):
        return Test(self.value+1)

    def g(self):
        return Test(self.value*2)

test1 = Test1()
```

Both `f` and `g` serves as functions on the class instance in some mathematical notation. For example, I desire to run `f(g(value))` in the notation. In the above class definition, the way to achieve it is by running `test1.g().f()`. Although there is nothing wrong with the code, I just don't like the fact that the order has changed, and it makes the line not that readable from a mathematics perspective.

I wonder if I could run the line like `f(g(value))` with some custom magic or dunder method, but could not find one.

I understand that the way to achieve it is simply taking `f` and `g` out from the class like:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def f(obj):
    return Test1(obj.value+1)

def g(obj):
     return Test1(obj.value*2)

test1 = Test1()
new_test = f(g(test1)
```

However, I have some other similar classes that also have the same function/method names (`f`, `g`). So, if I run

```
from Test1 import Test1, f, g
from Test2 import Test2, f, g
```

there will be obvious conflicts. I understand that I could do things like

```
from Test1 import Test1, f as f1, g as g1
from Test2 import Test2, f as f2, g as g2
```

but, not that pleasant with this.

Is there any custom package like `functools` that provide any ways? What I am expecting is something like

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @some_special_stuff
    def f(self):
        return Test(self.value+1)

    @some_special_stuff
    def g(self):
        return Test(self.value*2)

test1 = Test1()
new_test = f(g(test1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No. If you want the syntax `f(g(...))`, that's the *functional* approach and you need to define independent *functions* and need to take care of their naming. `t.g().f()` is the OOP approach and requires, well, OOP. There's no Objective Functional approach that also doesn't get into naming conflicts, at least not in Python.

Comment: Also, you should like that the order has changed. `test1.g().f()` makes the execution order immediately obvious, whereas the `f(g(..))` seems less readable. It also keeps nesting levels lower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Test1` and `Test2` classes have the same interface. We can model that

```py
from typing import Protocol

# using a protocol here, so we don't have to explicitly inherit from TestProtocol
class TestProtocol(Protocol):
    value: int
    def f(self) -> 'TestProtocol': ...
    def g(self) -> 'TestProtocol': ...
```

Now we know the interface and can define the free function `f` and `g` in terms of that interface:

```py
def f(test: TestProtocol) -> TestProtocol:
    return test.f()


def g(test: TestProtocol) -> TestProtocol:
    return test.g()
```

Now the free functions `f` and `g` are compatible with every class that implements the protocol:

```py
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value
    
    def f(self) -> 'Test1':
        return Test1(self.value + 1)
    
    def g(self) -> 'Test1':
        return Test1(self.value * 2)


class Test2:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value
    
    def f(self) -> 'Test2':
        return Test2(self.value - 1)
    
    def g(self) -> 'Test2':
        return Test2(self.value // 2)


print(f(g(Test1(4))).value)  # 9
print(f(g(Test2(4))).value)  # 1
```

Actually, you don't need the protocol at all. If you don't care about mypy, remove all type hints and the protocol.

So here is the "short" form without type hints:

```py
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def f(self):
        return Test1(self.value + 1)
    
    def g(self):
        return Test1(self.value * 2)

class Test2:
    ...

def f(test):
    return test.f()


def g(test):
    return test.g()


print(f(g(Test1(4))).value)
print(f(g(Test2(4))).value)
```

Comment: Personally, I believe your answer is the closest to meet the need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use `classmethods`:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def f(cls, instance):
        return cls(instance.value+1)

    @classmethod
    def g(cls, instance):
        return cls(instance.value*2)
```

Now your code can be rewritten like so:

```
test1 = Test1()
new_test = Test1.f(Test1.g(test1))
```

BTW however, I agree with the comments — I don't see anything particularly wrong with the method-chaining approach, which I personally find more readable.

Another solution might be to take the functions outside of the class, as you suggest.  You say you have multiple classes with methods named `f` and `g` — if  `f` and `g` do the same thing in every class, you could take `f` and `g` out of all your classes, put them in a module independent of all of them, and rewrite your functions so that they will work no matter what class is passed into them, like so:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

# f and g are now in a different module so will need to be imported separately to Test1

def f(instance):
    return instance.__class__(instance.value+1)

def g(instance):
    return instance.__class__(instance.value*2)
```

Now these functions will work no matter what kind of object is passed into them, providing the object has a `value` attribute and a compatible `__init__` signature, so you can rewrite your code as:

```
test1 = Test1()
new_test = f(g(test1))
```

If `f` and `g` do different things in each class, then you could take them out of your classes, put them in an independent module, and use `functions.singledispatch` to register different implementations depending on the kind of object that is passed into the function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html. E.g.

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def f(instance: object):
    raise NotImplementedError

@f.register
def _(instance: Test1):
    """Implementation if an instance of type Test1 is passed in"""
    return Test1(instance.value+1)

@f.register
def _(instance: Test2)
"""Implementation if an instance of type Test2 is passed in"""
    return Test2(instance.value+5)
```

Comment: I would probably use `type(instance)(instance.value+1)` instead of accessing `__class__` directly.

Comment: Also, `Test.f(Test.g(test1))` will work for ordinary instance methods as well. `function.__get__` is defined to return the function itself (rather than an instance of `method`) when the attribute is accessed via the class instead of an instance.

Comment: @chepner — yeah, I go back and forth as to whether I prefer type(obj) or obj.__class__. Usually I agree with you, but here I feel like obj.__class__ is a little more expressive for what we're trying to achieve? But just my opinion.

Comment: A similar comment on your second point, actually @chepner! Just because you could do Test.f(Test.g(test1)) with an ordinary instance method doesn't mean you should, right? It feels like slightly unexpected behaviour to be creating a new instance from an instance method, whereas you see that pattern a lot more often in classmethods.

Comment: Right. The class method approach is more amenable to subclassing, since you aren't hard-coding the parent class `Test` in the definition. Creating a new instance in an instance method is quite common, though; consider `__add__`, for example.

Comment: The more I think about this, though, the more I lean towards using the class methods over external functions: it keeps any direct references to the `value` attribute inside the class, rather than making ordinary functions aware of `Test` implementation details.

Comment: Yes. Though in some ways, the premise of the question seems to be striving to get away from the OOP paradigm, so I sort of like the singledispatch solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special to do in the class definition. `f` and `g` are ordinary functions; they behave differently when accessed via an instance of the class due to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

The main issue is the namespace in which you have a reference to the two functions. As written, the functions are *only* bound to class attributes. You can pull references to them into your local namespace.

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def f(self):
        return Test(self.value+1)

    def g(self):
        return Test(self.value*2)



test1 = Test1()
f = Test1.f
g = Test1.g

newtest = f(g(test1))
```

Of course, the names `f` and `g` aren't necessary; you can just write `newest = Test.f(Test.g(test1))`, which I alluded to in a comment on [Alex Waygood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68346921/1126841)

---

Note that it's technically possible for the class to push references *out* to the global namespace:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def f(self):
        return Test(self.value+1)

    def g(self):
        return Test(self.value*2)

    globals()['f'] = f
    globals()['g'] = g
```

but this is a bad idea for a number of reasons:

1. It's an odd thing for `Test1` to be responsible for
2. It's limited to the global scope, as you can't grab
   references to arbitrary local scopes (and indeed, the local
   scope you want to use it in may not even exist yet; they are created at runtime when you call a function).
3. It might override other variables named `f` and `g` in the global scope, and someone else may override `f` and `g` themselves. Related to point 1, `Test1` has no business making decisions about what should be defined in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator` module provides a way of wrapping method calls in a callable.

```
from operator import methodcaller

# methodcaller('foo')(x) == x.foo()
f = methodcaller('f')
g = methodcaller('g')

test = Test1()
newest = f(g(test1))
```

This is basically the same technique as in [Wombatz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68347626/1126841), but can be invoked dynamically without needing a `def` statement, and has less runtime overhead.

```
newest = methodcaller('f')(methodcaller('g')(test1))
```

Note that `methodcaller` is slightly more efficient than the equivalent use of a lambda expression,

```
newest = (lambda x: x.f())((lambda x: x.g())(test1))
```

due to more work being pulled into the interpreter itself, rather than having to be done at the interpreted level. (And there are fewer parentheses to deal with.)